# How to reserve screen space for GTK window?

Tags: python, binding, gtk3, gjs

It [can be done](https://gist.github.com/johnlane/351adff97df196add08a) with this code in python:

```js
topw = window.get_toplevel().window
topw.property_change("_NET_WM_STRUT","CARDINAL",32,gtk.gdk.PROP_MODE_REPLACE, [0, 0, bar_size, 0])
topw.property_change("_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL","CARDINAL",32,gtk.gdk.PROP_MODE_REPLACE, [0, 0, bar_size, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x, x+width, 0, 0])
```

But is there `property_change` binding in GJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/johnlane/351adff97df196add08a#file-dockbar-gtk3-py) is how to do it in Gtk3:

```
display = Display()
topw = display.create_resource_object('window',
                                       window.get_toplevel().get_window().get_xid())
topw.change_property(display.intern_atom('_NET_WM_STRUT'),
                       display.intern_atom('CARDINAL'), 32,
                       [0, 0, bar_size, 0 ],
                       X.PropModeReplace)

topw.change_property(display.intern_atom('_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL'),
                       display.intern_atom('CARDINAL'), 32,
                       [0, 0, bar_size, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x, x+width-1, 0, 0],
                       X.PropModeReplace)
```

You need the following imports:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk','3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import Xlib
from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib import X
```

I [confirmed via the mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/python-hackers-list/2017-February/msg00001.html) that, as @ptomato stated, the function is non-introspectable which means that it isn't available in introspected bindings such as Python.

---

**Additional Information**

You can do this in Ruby (either gtk2 or gtk3 bindings). You need to `require 'xlib-objects'` and then, from an instance of (a subclass of) `Gtk::Window`:

```
topw = XlibObj::Window.new(XlibObj::Display.new(':0'),
            toplevel.window.xid)
XlibObj::Window::Property.new(topw, '_NET_WM_STRUT').set(
            [0, 0, self.height, 0 ],
            :CARDINAL)
XlibObj::Window::Property.new(topw, '_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL').set(
            [0, 0, self.height, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x, x+width-1, 0, 0], 
            :CARDINAL)
```

Alternatively you can use `xprop` to do it via `system` subshell:

```
xid = toplevel.window.xid
system %Q{xprop -id #{xid} -format _NET_WM_STRUT 32c \
                           -set _NET_WM_STRUT \
                           "0, 0, #{self.height}, 0"}
system %Q{xprop -id #{xid} -format _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL 32c \
                           -set _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL \
          "0, 0, #{self.height}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, #{x}, #{x+width-1}, 0, 0"}
```

Finally, to do it from the command-line:

```
$ xprop -id 44040195 -format _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL 32c -set _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL "0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1600, 3519, 0, 0"
```

(where `-id 44040195` specifies the window it; omit to select window with mouse)

To view the settings from the command-line:

```
$ xprop _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL _NET_WM_STRUT
```

Answer (score 1):

Alas, `gdk_property_change()` is [marked non-introspectable](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gdk/gdkwindow.c#n11191) so there is no binding in GJS, PyGObject, etc.

As you show, PyGTK did support it, but that's old and you can't use GTK 3 with it.