# What is the replacement for self.window which is now deprecated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, pygtk

I am using Python 3 and GTK 3 running rhel8 porting a script that was using Python 2.7 and Gtk 2.

Running the script gives an error: 'X' object has no attribute 'window', previous version of python and gtk did not complain.

```
class XWindow(Gtk.Window):
     def __init__(self, wtype = Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL):
          Gtk.Window.__init__(self, wtype)
class X(XWindow):
     def __init__(self, vpos, mgr):
         XWindow.__init__( self )
         ...
         ...
         ...
     def XFunction:
         if self.window:
            ...
            ...
            self.window.property_change(...)
```

Comment: error `'X' object has no attribute 'window'` doesn't mean it deprecated - it only means that `window` doesn't exist - and probably it never existed in `GTK 3`. `GTK 3` and `GTK 2` may have totally different code and sometimes you can't compare them.

Comment: I don't know what `self.window` should be - but for me `self` is already a `window` (a `Gtk.Window`). Did you try `if self: self.property_change(...)` . OR  maybe you forgot somewhere in class `X` to do `self.window = SomeOtherWindow()`

Comment: `self.propery_change` complains about `property_change` not existing as well. Before porting my script I never had to explicitly declare `self.window = anything`. It seemed to know to refer to itself, I guess my question is how to I refer to the window that is implicitly created when the window object is created?

Comment: @furas forgot to tag

Comment: better show original code which work in Python 2.

Comment: @furas Aside from some spelling changes to the XWindow class (e.g. gtk to Gtk, etc.), what I posted is the same code from Python 2. self.window was never explicitly defined.

Comment: if I run `help(XWindow)` in `Python 2` then it shows that `window` is inherited from `gtk.Widget` and it is `"data descriptor"` (whatever it means). I didn't check `help(XWindow)` in `Python 3`, yet, but you could check it or check in documentation for `GTK2` to see what `window` means and then you may search it in documentation for `GTK3`

Comment: when I run code in Python 2 then `self.window` gives me `None` so this part of code is never executed. So maybe this part of code can be skiped. If it can't be skiped then probably it will have to rewrite all using totally different functions - and convertion will need a lot of work.

Comment: @furas I went to see what the value of `self.window` was on my rhel7 system with Python 2 and it returned `gtk.gdk.Window object at 0x7ff31a256eb0 (GdkWindow at 0x1026360)`

Also `help(XWindow)` in my Python 3 file revealed that there is nothing `window` related anymore...

Comment: I saw some tutorial and examples for `GTK 2` and it looks like it threats main window like `Application` and it assing real window (`gdk.Window`) to `self.window`. But `GTK 3` works in different way and it doen't creates `self.window` and you can access real window using `self.` - but `GTK3` may have other changes - and it may not have `property_change()` and it would need to find other function for this - so all code may need a lot of changes.

Answer (score 1):

PyGTK is now unmaintained and has been replaced by PyGObject (a generic wrapper for all GObject libraries).

The `gtk.Widget.window` equivalent is [`Gtk.Widget.get_window()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.get_window):

> **Returns:**  `self`’s window.
>
> **Return type:**  `Gdk.Window` or `None`
>
> Returns the widget’s window if it is realized, `None` otherwise

There is no PyGObject equivalent for `gtk.gdk.Window.property_change`. The function still exists in Gdk3 [`gdk_property_change()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk3/func.property_change.html) but is "non-introspectable" so there are no [GObject introspection](https://gi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) bindings (which is what PyGObject uses).

See [How to reserve screen space for GTK window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33719686/8944057) for a workaround using [`python-xlib`](https://pypi.org/project/python-xlib/).

---

Note that `Gtk.Widget.get_window()` will only return a `Gdk.Window` if the widget has been [realized](https://people.gnome.org/%7Ejohnp/girdocsalpha/Gtk/Gtk.Widget.realize.html). Some widgets (e.g. `Gtk.Label`) will use their parent widget's `Gdk.Window` (see documentation for [`gtk_widget_set_has_window()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Widget.set_has_window.html)) and return that if realized.

See [Widget Concepts from *GTK+/Gnome Application Development*](https://book.huihoo.com/gtk+-gnome-application-development/z57.html#SEC-REALIZINGSHOWING) for more details on the widget lifecycle.

Also properties of GObjects in PyGObject are accessible via the `GObject.Object.props` attribute, so alternatively you could use `Gtk.Widget.props.window` to access a widget's `Gdk.Window`. Basically all (all that I've come across) properties have an associated `get_xxx()` and `set_xxx()` method in the PyGObject bindings, so you can use those or via `props` if you prefer using property syntax.

See the [PyGObject docs on properties](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/api/properties.html) for more details.